# largest sum of consecutive values

Tags: algorithm

> There are N hotels along the beautiful Adriatic coast. Each hotel has
>   its value in Euros.
>
> Sroljo has won M Euros on the lottery. Now he wants to buy a sequence
>   of consecutive hotels, such that the sum of the values of these
>   consecutive hotels is as great as possible - but not greater than M.

I was asked to calculate the greatest possible value.
my code was:

```
big=-1;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    sum=0;
    for(j=i;j<n;j++)
    {
        sum+=A[j];
        if(sum<m) 
            {B[i]=sum;continue;}
        if(sum>m)
            {B[i]=(sum-A[j]); break;}
        if(sum==m)
            {printf("%d\n",m); exit(1);}

     }
     if(B[i]>big)
        big=B[i];
}
printf("%lld",big);
```

, which is O(n^2) and too slow for my purposes. how can this be done in O(n)?

Comment: Isnt that a special case of 'knapsack problem'?

Comment: @micka indeed, but that doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Why the downvotes for this question? Is it because the asker was begging the answerer for pseudocode?

Comment: @JanDvorak, I think because `http://www.spoj.com/problems` created not for `on stackoverflow solving`...

Comment: are allowed questions like this here? It helps to convert brain problems to google problems. I think, it isn't very well...

Comment: i got my answer. just wanted to know the concept ."moving window" it is.

Comment: @vp_arth good point. What if the part about SPOJ was edited out? This question looks like it could be useful for future readers.

Comment: @JanDvorak it's more about the way it's answered than the way it's asked. If SPOJ user can't find a solution here, he/she can ask in million other places and get it anyway.

Comment: @JanDvorak Of course "do it for me plz, k thx bai" questions are downvoted and closed almost instantly. Really tough call sometimes.

Comment: @this question does show effort, however. Also, the primary criterion for voting should be usefulness, not just the amount effort. Of course, lazy questions are duplicates and not useful.

Comment: @soulcheck how do you rate this question now?

Comment: @JanDvorak it's well formed, clear and contains what we have to assume is OP's best effort to solve the problem. I see no reason to downvote it.

Comment: @JanDvorak, good work, thanks) I remove my downvote

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here's how, without making it too obvious for future googlers.

Put the hotels in a list in order they appear from left to right.

Use a "moving window" starting at index i and ending on j (i <= j), while maintaining the current sum (`s`) of prices of the hotels in that window. The task is to find greatest `s` such that `s <= M`.

You can extend the window window to the right (on the `j` side) if the sum of prices contained in the window (`s`) doesn't exceed Sroljo's budget.

You have to shrink the window from the left (on the `i` side) if the sum has exceeded Sroljo's budget.

You can maintain at each step maximum legal sum found so far, updating it accordingly.

After moving the window through all the positions obtained from this algo, the maximum sum found so far is what you're looking for.

Comment: @user3210882 that would make it a bit too easy, wouldn't it?

Comment: @vp_arth no, each index is moved at most n times, each time there's only constant number of things to update. so O(n).

Comment: Good simple approach. I don't think it's a problem to post complete solutions here though (or pseudocode). When somebody googles for the solution, he should expect to find spoilers